# FireBug 1.7.3 won't break on any error, after continuing, even "debugger" statements

Tags: debugging, firebug, breakpoints, continue

There's an error in my code where a function is called, and the function doesn't exist.  It doesn't matter, since it's just a callback that's unimportant.  So when FireBug stopped on this error, I pressed the arrow button (F8) Continue.  But now, it refuses to stop on ANY error. It happily reports the improper function call but doesn't stop.  It reaches "debugger" and happily ignores it!  So I restart a new debugging session, and it remembers all of this, and still refuses to stop on any error.

Why does the arrow (F8) Continue button mean "ignore this error, and never break on any error again for the lifetime of your workstation"?  And how do I turn this off?  And further, how can I shut this ridiculous behaviour off forever?

Thanks for any help! :)

---

Since I cannot answer my own question for 7 more hours, I'll add my answer here:

**QUICK FIX:** Clicking on the firebug icon (in the firebug window, not the one that opens/closes the window), selecting Options, then selecting Reset All Firebug Options cleared this up.

I'm still dumbfounded ... I just don't understand why (F8) Continue does anything but continue once on that single line of code.  It shouldn't auto-continue on the same line of code later.  It definitely shouldn't auto-continue if you relaunch Firefox.  And it absolutely should not auto-continue on other errors.

Comment: Try answering it now. This is what's annoying about SO at first. Once you get to 200 rep you have 100 rep on all the SO sites. I just found out this today.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the firebug icon (in the firebug window, not the one that opens/closes the window), selecting Options, then selecting Reset All Firebug Options cleared this up.